# Nginx Load Balance - 2 servers, 2 IP, 1 domain

Tags: nginx

I have two servers with 2 different IPs. They both have NginX installed and I wish to loadbalance the traffic between them for one particular domain.

Server1 - IP-1 - 1 Domain

Server2 - IP-2 - Lost of domains

How to I set up the corresponding nginx configs for the only site that I wish to autobalance? I want Server1 to be always served but when it drops down, then Server2 would serve the same domain name. What IP should I assign to the URL that I want to server? IP-1 or IP-2? Do I need a 3rd server to act as a gateway?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 3rd server as load balancer (point there your hostname).

This could be another nginx server or a more specific load balancer as [ahproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).

If you wish to go down the nginx path, create a new server and put into the *http* section something like

```
upstream mywebsite {
    server 192.168.1.20:80;
    server 192.168.1.30:80 backup;
}
```

Then create a vhost for your website and put into the *server* section

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://mywebsite;
}
```

Note the *backup* variable, it specify to use the secondary server only if the primary is down, because by default requests are distributed between the servers using a weighted round-robin balancing method.

Be sure to check out the [ngx_http_upstream_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) documentation for more options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to test it now without a 3rd computer by giving 2 IP for the same domain. It is not a very good test at all, but I can see that the traffic is being seperated just as I've expected. Created the proxy forwarder on both servers just 4fun and they work. If the primary goes down, then the backup comes in place (That is my goal overall) Thank you for your advice, I'll let the boss know that we need a 3rd VPS.

Oh, and I use nginx instead of Haproxy because NginX is better loadbalancing than HAProxy.

[link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQvcHy_tPjI[/link]

Comment: @Bert "Oh, and I use nginx instead of Haproxy because NginX is better loadbalancing than HAProxy." The "proof" of this claim is the linked video?